# How are duplicate sim cards detected by the provider?

Tags: gsm

why can't you use an original and a cloned sim card at the same time? How does the provider detects that both are trying to connect to the network? I have been reading about the authentication process but I am still a little confused and I need more specific reasons as to why this happens.

Thank you

Comment: What would you do if you were a provider? I would make sure ppl couldn't use cloned cards (at the same time).

Comment: Definitely, but how does it happen? I know sim cards have a unique IMSI,Ki and ICCID numbers. Which one does the provider use to detect this?. Does it recognizes 2 equal IMSI numbers and shuts them down?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mobile network operators run a subscriber database, the [HLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_Location_Register#Home_location_register_.28HLR.29).

Every SIM has a unique identity, the [IMSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_mobile_subscriber_identity). The HLR associates an IMSI with a subscriber by storing IMSI and subscriber data together.

When switching on a mobile phone, and afterwards in regular intervals, the phone registers its SIM with the network (a "location update" in telco speech). During the register procedure, the mobile network performs authentication and authorization against the HLR and marks the IMSI as being active. The authorization will fail if an IMSI is already marked as active. If the authorization failed, the network won't allow the mobile to access its services.

This has been built on purpose into the network architecture:

- since the network can deliver a call to one device only. There is no default functionality to have several devices ringing for calling a single number. (This is possible, but requires additional systems.)
- to prevent hostile take-over of numbers (delivering a call to a party it is not intended for).
- to prevent fraud, e.g. by not being a paying subscriber at all or, in your case, by using two devices on one contract.

Some network operators offer special products to overcome this on-purpose limitation. For example you may get an additional SIM, coded to your telephone number, which disables your first SIM when switched on. This is useful if you have a phone installed in your car requiring a separate SIM. In this case, there is logic in the HLR which supports switching SIMs.

Answer (score 3):

The HLR is NOT used to detect cloning. All it does is map an actual phone number to an IMSI, which is unique to the SIM card.

Providers use radio fingerprinting (where they can differentiate certain characteristics of the individual station's radio transmission channel lock) and when they detect that two stations are using the same combination of IMEI/IMSI/MIN but have a different RF fingerprint, they know something has been cloned.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_fingerprinting